# I want to call get_queryset on an object twice within a view template. How should I do it?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to build a web app that helps studying languages.
On the index page(home page), I want to show 2 sections: "Latest vocabulary" and "Random vocabulary".

Hence, I want to filter the Spanish vocabulary list using two filters separately. First one is to arrange them according to date of being added to the database, and the other is to randomize and draw 20 random words. I found the get_queryset() is a way to do the 1st filtering, and I found another way to randomize from stackoverflow as well. But the problem is, get_queryset() returns the result to context_object_name, and I suppose there can only exist one context_object_name. So I don't know how to fetch the random_spanish_list and display it.

Here is the code for the index page.

```
{% if latest_spanish_list %}
<div class="flexcontainer">
    <div class="sectiontitle">Latest vocabulary
    </div>
    {% for spanish in latest_spanish_list %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cardinner" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flipped');">
            <div class="cardfront">
                <a href="{% url 'geniusdennis:detail' spanish.id %}">{{ spanish.word_esp }}</a>
                <form action="/deleteword/{{spanish.id}}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            {% for english in spanish.english_set.all %}
            <div class="cardback">
                <p>{{ english.word_eng}}</p>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% else %}
    <p>No Spanish words are available.</p>
{% endif %}
{% if random_spanish_list %}
<div class="flexcontainer">
    <div class="sectiontitle">Random vocabulary
    </div>
    {% for spanish in random_spanish_list %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cardinner" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flipped');">
            <div class="cardfront">
                <a href="{% url 'geniusdennis:detail' spanish.id %}">{{ spanish.word_esp }}</a>
                <form action="/deleteword/{{spanish.id}}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            {% for english in spanish.english_set.all %}
            <div class="cardback">
                <p>{{ english.word_eng}}</p>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% else %}
    <p>No Spanish words are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And here is the code for the IndexView template.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'geniusdennis/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_spanish_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last 20 Spanish words (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """
        return Spanish.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:20]

    def get_queryset(self):
        # grab the max id in the database
        max_id = Spanish.objects.order_by('-id')[0].id

        random_id = random.randint(1, max_id + 1)

        Spanish.objects.filter(id__gte=random_id)[0]

        return random_spanish
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have pagination in your views then using `get_context_data()` might do the trick, though maybe there is a better way to do it but here's my take.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # grab the max id in the database
    max_id = Spanish.objects.order_by('-id')[0].id
    random_id = random.randint(1, max_id + 1)
    random_spanish = Spanish.objects.filter(id__gte=random_id)[0]

    context['random_spanish_list'] = random_spanish
    return context
```

Then you can just call for a loop on ***random_spanish_list*** in your template

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have seen this similar way to solve the problem as well. I will try, but I wonder what if I want to filter the "Spanish word list" using 3 different 3 methods?